# Akka Stream Parallelism

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I've been trying to parallelize a stream in Akka Stream, according to the documentation[1], but for some reason I don't get the expected result.

I followed the steps outlined in the documentation, and I don't think I missed anything. Yet, the computations of my stream all happen one after the other in sequence.

What am I missing here?

[1] https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-parallelism.html

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.FlowShape
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Balance, Flow, GraphDSL, Merge, Source}

object ScalaParallell extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("QuickStart")

  def longRunningComputation(x: Int): Int = {
    println(s"Computing 1 ${x}")
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    println(s"Computation 1 ${x} done")
    x
  }
  def longRunningComputation2(x: Int): Int = {
    println(s"Computing 2 ${x}")
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    println(s"Computation 2 ${x} done")
    x
  }

  val processor: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] =
    Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      // prepare graph elements
      val balance = b.add(Balance[Int](2))
      val merge = b.add(Merge[Int](2))
      val f = Flow[Int].map(longRunningComputation)
      val f2 = Flow[Int].map(longRunningComputation2)


      // connect the graph
      balance.out(0) ~> f.async ~> merge.in(0)
      balance.out(1) ~> f2.async ~> merge.in(1)

      // expose ports
      FlowShape(balance.in, merge.out)
    })


  // Wire it all up.
  val xs = List(1,2,3)
  val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(xs)
  source.via(processor).runForeach(println)


  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

Example output

```
Computing 2 1
Computation 2 1 done
Computing 2 2
1
Computation 2 2 done
Computing 2 3
2
Computation 2 3 done
3
```

I would expect to see two computations happening at the same time. For example:

```
Computing 1 1
Computing 1 2
Computation 1 2 done
Computing 1 3
Computation 1 1 done
Computing 2 4
1
2
..
```

Comment: But your code doesn't even call `longRunningComputation2`.

Comment: Right, I must have forgotten to put it back. I updated the output and the code accordingly. (Doesn't work either, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `Thread.sleep` inside `longRunningComputation` and `longRunningComputation2` and set `xs` to something much longer for example `1 to 100`, then you'll able to observe the parallel processing. Not sure why but the blocking `Thread.sleep` is definitely considered anti-pattern in akka

Comment: I tried starting from a larger range (1 to 100k) and that seemed to trigger the parallelism instantly. Thanks for the reply. Didn't think about.